# Can't use setPitchEnabled to change its value to YES

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I just ran into a weird bug. If I try setting 3D perspective on my `MKMapView` to `YES`, it is still set to `NO`.

Here is a sample code that retrieves… NO

```
[self.mapView setPitchEnabled:YES];
NSLog(@"Is Pitch enabled ? - Answer:  %hhd", [self.mapView isPitchEnabled]);
```

Output:

> Is Pitch enabled ? - Answer:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Doc:

> When this property is set to YES and a valid camera is associated with
>   the map, the camera’s pitch angle is used to tilt the plane of the
>   map.

I don't see you setting any camera.

A sample camera implementation:

```
MKMapCamera *newCamera = [[mapView camera] copy];
[newCamera setPitch:45.0];
[newCamera setHeading:90.0];
[newCamera setAltitude:500.0];
[mapView setCamera:newCamera animated:YES];
```

Comment: Yes. I had read that. But I thought the camera's default settings would prevail since initially it works. This is indeed the correct answer. Thanks !!!